# Thermocouple cause fixture no light?

Tags: bathroom, recessed-lighting

Can the thermocouple be bypassed in the shower stall recessed light fixture?  If not how should this be replaced?

Comment: Are you sure it is a thermocouple? Most fixtures have a thermal safety switch that opens when a lamp that is larger than the fixture is rated for is used (not safe to bypass a safety device).

Comment: Replace the fixture for one that is LED and does not require a light bulb.  For bonus points, replace the fixture with a low-voltage LED fixture and have everything in the shower be 12/24V.